# Projectile motion - gravity varying with height

Tags: python, recurring, projectile

The question is having to make a projectile motion where gravity isn't constant. So the position  s(t) = -0.5 g t2 + v0 t and g(s) = G∙ME / (RE + s)2. Where G, ME, and RE are all constants. Therefore the new equation is  s(t) = -0.5 g(s) t2 + v0 t.

I get to make the assumption that every .005 seconds velocity is constant so the equation has to update itself every .005 seconds. So s(t) = s(t-∆t) + v(t)∙∆t where v(t) = v(t-∆t) - g(s(t-∆t)) ∙ ∆t.

My code right now is

```
# Assigning Variables
G = 6.6742*10**(-11) # Gravitational Constant
M_e = 5.9736*10**(24) # Mass of Earth
R_e = 6371000 # Radius of Earth
t = float(input('Time (in seconds)')) # Asking user to input total time, t
v_0 = float(input('initial velocity')) # Asking user to input initial velocity
t_0 = .005 # Time before first recalculation 
g = 9.81 # initial gravity

# Derivative of s(t) = s't = v(t)
# v(t) = -g(s)*t+v_o

while t != t_0:
    s = v_0*t_0
    g = (g*M_e)/(R_e+s)**2
    v = -g*s*t_0+v_0
    t_0=t_0+.005
    if int(t_0) == t_0:
        print'Gravity is {%f}, position is {%f}, and velocity is {%f} at time {%.0f}' %(g, s, v, t_0)
print'Projectile has reached your time {%f}, with gravity {%f}, position {%f}, and velocity {%f}'%(t,g,s,v)
```

I really don't know how I am supposed to change it so it will work.

So I updated it as the suggestions that I got. Now when I run it my program asks for time and initial velocity and time (in seconds). However it does not even produce an output.

Time (in seconds)5

initial velocity5

That's how the result looks like when I input 5 for both.

Comment: How exactly does it "not work"? Is there an error? If so, include the *full traceback*.

Answer (score 1):

I've added comments to your code, along with some changes so the program will run (at least on 2.7.6). However, while it will *run*, it won't truly work. You should look at your functions for s, g, and v - they are not correct. For example R_e * s will not give you the distance from the center of the earth, as its units are now metres^2.

```
# Assigning Variables
G = 6.6742*10**(-11) # Gravitational Constant
M_e = 5.9736*10**(24) # Mass of Earth
##### In your code the commas are making this a tuple, not an integer - it needs to be defined without commas. 
R_e = 6371000 # Radius of Earth
t = float(input('Time (in seconds)'))
v_0 = float(input('initial velocity'))
t_0 = .005
#You need to define an initial g
g = 9.81

while t != t_0:
    ####In your code you had a typo here - t_o instead of t_0
    s = v_0*t_0
    ####If you don't initialise g, this function does not know what g is. 
    g = (g*M_e)/(R_e*s)**2
    v = -g*s*t_0+v_0
    t_0=t_0+.005
    #####If you want to check if the type of t_0 is an integer, you need to use the type function. It will also never be an integer, as you are always adding a float to a float in the line above this. 
    if type(t_0) == int:
        print('Gravity is {%f}, position is {%f}, and velocity is {%f} at time {%.0f}' %(g, s, v, t_0))
####No need for an if statement to tell if the while loop is finished - just put the print statement after the while loop. 
print('Projectile has reached your time {%f}, with gravity {%f}, position {%f}, and velocity {%f}'%(t,g,s,v))
```

Comment: I don't believe that part is wrong because that is simply the equation giving for g. The distance from the center of the earth is supposed to be squared. Thanks for the help rabs.

Comment: Yes - you have R_e * s, but then you square that again, giving m^4. If you want the distance from the center of the earth it should be R_e + s - then you square that.

Comment: It should be `R_e + s`, but only if you're firing your projectile up.

Comment: Yeah - he seems to only be using one axis at the moment.

Comment: With t_0 being equal to an integer I'm trying to say a while number. so like 1.000000 and so on. Another way to say that is 1/.005 time, so each 200th time I want to print out the response. Do you know of a way I could do that?